# Wix Build Order - msbuild & Heat

Tags: msbuild, wix

I am trying to extend our existing Wix Project with Heat to include all files from the output directory of another project in the installer. Somehow I`m missing something that should be very easy since I guess this is a very common task.

Here is what the solution looks like:

```
SomeDependencyA.csproj
SomeDependencyB.csproj (Depends on SomeDependencyA)
WindowsService.csproj (Depends on SomeDependencyB)
Installer.wixproj(Depends on WindowsService.csproj)
```

Wix should basically grep anything from WindowsService Output folder and build the msi package from it. The process should be:

- Build all Dependencies
- Build WindowsService project
- Generate a Fragement using Heat
- Build the Installer

And here is my question: Where/how do I have to include the call to Heat? Pre-Build Step and BeforeBuild Target does not work, since at this time the WindowsService and the Dependencies are not Build yet. AfterBuild wouldn´t help, since at that point the generated Fragment would not be cosidered anymore. I was looking for some build target that is calles AFTER all dependencies have been build but BEFORE the Installer Project itself has been build. Should be easy, but I couldn´t figure it out yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BeforeBuild target will happen potentially before a dependant project has completed its build.

A solution I've used for this type of build ordering in the past is to add a DependsOnTargets for the BeforeBuild target;

For csproj:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild" DependsOnTargets="ResolveReferences">
```

For vcxproj:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
```

This will force the project to wait until the dependant projects are completed before running the BeforeBuild target.